# Only serialise certain properties with Knockout toJSON

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have a view model with quite a lot of properties, but I only want to serialise two observable arrays using the toJSON method. Is this possible?

I did come across one article that said to do something like this:

```
var json = ko.toJSON(self, ["rates", "discounts"]);
```

But that just produces the following:

```
{"rates":[{},{},{},{},{},{}],"discounts":[{},{},{},{}]}
```

It's the correct number of rates and discounts, but they're all empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
var json = ko.toJSON({ rates: self.rates, discounts: self.discounts  });
```

Or use ko.mapping plugin where you can configure which members to include

Answer (score 0):

You can user Array.map to flatten the items in the array.

This should do the trick:

```
function flattenArrayItem(arrayItem) {
  var result = {
      prop1: arrayItem.prop1,
      prop2: arrayItem.prop2
      // continue mapping needed properties
  }; 
  return result; 
}

// if observable array
var json = ko.toJSON(someArray().map(flattenArrayItem));
// if normal array
var json = ko.toJSON(someArray.map(flattenArrayItem));
```

Comment: Isn't it too complicated ?

Comment: It might be, but it separates out the mapping so that it could be reused somewhere else if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think I'll go with Anders' solution, as it's all I need, and I won't need to reuse it.